# Identifying relevant SNPs from a list

Tags: bioinformatics, dna-sequence, genome

I have a list of all SNPs in CDS of several thousand genes, and I'm looking for a convenient method to come up with a list of known SNPs that alter an amino acid in those genes.

I'll be glad to hear your thoughts.

Thanks

Comment: I think you should read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and then maybe post your question in https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/ where it might have a better chance to get answered.

Comment: cross posted: http://seqanswers.com/forums/showthread.php?t=79321